# Reference marker on Google Fusion Table Map

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am trying to simulate a click on a marker that is being plotted via Google Fusion Tables. How do you reference a marker that way?

I do not want to create a new Marker, just simulate a click on one that is already there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to trigger a click event on a FusionTablesLayer (at least at the present time).  You can query the table and open an infoWindow with the same information in it (but that isn't the same thing, and requires some work).

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a work-around. I just needed to display an info window once the map loads. So, I created a new info-window and added that to the map.